# How to replace a string in a file in linux that have "/" in it?

Tags: linux, string, bash, sed, grep

I want to replace a string (which is a name of a directory) like "/home/xyz/", to "/home/abc/" in multiple files through terminal. Usual replace command like sed does not seem to work with "/". Can anyone suggest anything ?

Comment: What does your `sed` command look like?

Answer (score 0):

Sed works just fine on strings with slashes. Just a) escape the slashes or b) pick a different delimiter that's not part of the string.

```
echo "/home/xyz/"|sed 's@/home/xyz/@/home/abc/@'
```